# Moving files into a sub directory talend automatic

Tags: etl, talend

I want to move folders into another directory using talend. Right now I have the folders inside a directory, and I want to move them into another sub-directory before starting my work on them. 
Any ideas how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tFileList component to iterate on the files in the specified source directory and tFileCopy component to move the files as shown below. Make sure that the File Name is grabbed from the tFileList as shown and that the Remove Source File is selected to remove the file from the original directory. Hope this helps.

[image]